# Importing classes/functions with same name as module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Say I use a python package with the following structure:

```
package/
   bar.py
   foo.py
   __init__.py
```

`bar.py` contains the class `bar` and `foo.py` contains the function `foo`.
When I want to import the function/class do I have to write

```
from package.bar import bar
from package.foo import foo
```

or can I write

```
from package import bar
from package import foo
```

More generally asked:
Can I always omit the class/function name, when I import a module with the same name as the class/function?

Comment: If you do `from package import bar` then the `bar` function in the `bar` module is available as `bar.bar`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't omit the module or object name. There is no mechanism that'll implicitly do such imports.

From the [*Zen of Python*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Note that importing the *module itself* should always be a valid option too. If `from package import bar` imported the `package.bar.bar` object instead, then you'd have to go out of your way to get access to `package.bar` module itself.

Moreover, such implicit behaviour (auto-importing the object contained in a module rather than the module itself) leads to confusing inconsistencies.

- What does `import package.bar` add to your namespace? Would referencing `package.bar` be the module or the contained object?
- What should happen to code importing such a name, when you rename the contained object? Does `from package import bar` then give you the module instead? Some operations will still succeed, leading to weird, hard to debug errors, instead of a clear `ImportError` exception.

Generally speaking, Python modules rarely contain just *one* thing. Python is not Java, modules consist of closely related groups of objects, not just one class or function.

Now, there is an inherent namespace collision in packages; `from package import foo` can refer both to names set on the `package` module, *or* to a nested module name. Python will first look at the `package` namespace in that case.

This means you *can* make an explicit decision to provide the `foo` and `bar` objects at the package level, in `package/__init__.py`:

```
# in package/__init__.py
from .foo import foo
from .bar import bar
```

Now `from package import foo` and `from package import bar` will give you those objects, masking the nested modules.

The general mechanism of importing objects from submodules into the package namespace is a common method of composing your public API whilst still using internal modules to group your code logically. For example, the [`json.JSONDecodeError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#exceptions) in the Python standard library is defined in the `json.exceptions` module, then imported into `json/__init__.py`. I generally would discourage *masking submodules* however; but `foo` and `bar` into a module with a different name.

Comment: While this is good advice in the spirit of how python is, it is perhaps hard not to say that this state of affairs lends to unnecessary complexity (or just call it lack of simplifying aesthetics or something) whenever the coding style follows the single-class per file philosophy.

Comment: @matanster: that philosophy goes against how Python modules, conceptually, work. Don't do that.